# Accumulating votes in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, hashmap, object-recognition

First, a little background to my problem:

I am building an object recognition system using a geometric hashing technique. My hash table is indexed by the affine co-ordinates of points in a model determined by a basis triplet (allowing an affine invariant representation of any learned object). Each hash table entry is a structure :

```
entry = struct('ModelName', modelName, 'BasisTriplet', [a; b; c])];
```

Now, an arbitrary basis triplet is extracted from image points then the affine co-ordinates of all other points are calculated relative to this basis and used as indices to the hash table. For each entry that exists in this hash bin, a vote is cast for the modelName and basis triplet. 
After checking all points, the models and their corresponding basis triplets with a sufficiently high number of votes are taken as candidates for an object and a further verification step is performed.

---

I am unsure however what is the most efficient method of casting these votes. Currently I am using a dynamic cell array, each time a new model and basis triplet pair is voted for, an additional row is added to the array. Otherwise the vote count of an existing candidate is incremented.

```
    for keylist = 1:length(keylist)
        % Where keylist is an array of indicies to the relevant keys to look up
        % xkeys is the n by 2 array of all of the keys in the hash table
        % Obtain this hash bin
        bin = hashTable(xkeys(keylist(i), 1), xkeys(keylist(i), 2));
        % Vote for every entry in the bin
        for entry = 1:length(bin)
            % Find the index of this model/basis in the voting accumulator
            indAcc = find( strcmp(bin.ModelName, v_models(:, 1)) & myIsEqual(v_basisTriplets, bin.BasisTriplet) );
            if isempty(indAcc)
                % If entries do not exist yet, Add new entries
                v_models = [v_models; {bin.ModelName, 1}]; 
                v_basisTriplets = cat(3, v_basisTriplets, bin.BasisTriplet);
            else
                % Otherwise increment the count
                v_models(indAcc, 2) = v_models(indAcc, 2)+1;
            end
        end
    end
```

There is a separate 3D array (v_basisTriplets) in which the 2D basis array is concatenated and indexed along the 3rd dimension. I did have these basis triplets in the cell array also, however I had difficulty searching this cell array for a 2D array. The myIsEqual function just searches through the third dimension and checks if the 2D array at each index is equal, returning a 1D vector of which arrays are equal for use in the find.

```
function ind = myIsEqual(vec3D, A)

    ind = zeros(size(vec3D, 3), 1);
    for i = 1:size(vec3D, 3)
        ind(i) = isequal(vec3D(:, :, i), A);
    end
```

This is most certainly not the most efficient way. Immediately I can see that it would be more efficient to initialize the arrays to store the votes beforehand. However however is there a better way in general of going about this? I need to try and find the most efficient and elegant way of voting as there are usually hundreds of points to check and time is valuable.

Thanks

Comment: To get complete answers, I think you're going to need to create some sample data so that the code-block is runnable.  There are too many interrelating structures to absorb by looking at code.  But as a general comment, think about replacing the string `ModelName` with a number which indexes a cell array of ModelNames.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only considering time efficiency, consider using a 4d matrix.

The dimensions would be:

- Model
- coordinateA
- coordinateB
- coordinateC

Depending on the ratio between this matrix size and the amount of points that you check, consider using a sparse matrix.

Note that especially if you can't use a sparse array, this method can be rather memory inefficient and may therefore be infeasible.